# What is registered query in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

What is registered query in MarkLogic and what is the use case?

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:registered-query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MarkLogic has a pretty good explanation in the Search Developer's Guide:

> If you use the same complex cts:query expressions repeatedly, and if
>   you are using them as an unfiltered cts:query constructor, you can
>   register the cts:query expressions for later use. Registering a
>   cts:query expression stores a pre-evaluated version of the expression,
>   making it faster for subsequent queries to use the same expression.
>   Unfiltered constructors return results directly from the indexes and
>   return all candidate fragments for a search, but do not perform
>   post-filtering to validate that each fragment perfectly meets the
>   search criteria.

Here's the HTML version of that guide: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/cts_query. It's very thorough and includes examples.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find anything through google, and didn't even thought to look through the guide

Comment: Maybe this will get indexed and help the next Googler :)

Comment: Useful answer. Thanks